# How to delete product from Wishlist in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have wishlist table in my Django database, and `customer` related to wishlist table, it means if a customer is logged in then he/she can add product in `wishlist`, but i am trying to delete product from customer wishlist, but it's redirecting back, please let me know how I can delete products from customer wishlist.

here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def deletewishlist(request, id):
    customer=request.user.customer
    Wishlist.objects.filter(customer_id=customer.id, id=id).delete()
    messages.success(request, 'Product Remove From Wishlist...')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/wishlist')
```

here is my `urls.py` file...

```
path('wishlist_item/deleteproduct/<int:id>', views.deletewishlist, name="deletewishlist"),
```

here is my `delete` button code, which delete products from wishlist when click...

```
<a class="primary-btn" href="/wishlist_item/deleteproduct/{{item.product.id}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure')">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying the `Wishlist` id instead of `product` id

Use:

```
def deletewishlist(request, id):
    customer=request.user.customer
    Wishlist.objects.filter(customer_id=customer.id, product=Product.objects.get(id=id)).delete()
    messages.success(request, 'Product Remove From Wishlist...')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/wishlist')
```

Comment: can you solve this issue...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465861/how-to-stop-folder-name-to-store-in-databse-in-django