# How to stop Folder name to Store in Databse in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am uploading Image in my specific folder, but it's storing in my database table also, Please let me know how I can stop folder name to store in database. Currently my image is storing in my database table in this format `thumb/20/08/18/image.jpeg`, i don't want this `thumb/20/08/18` to store in my database table, because it's my folder name with year, date and month.

Here is my `models.py` file..

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    thumb_image= models.ImageField(upload_to='thumb/%y/%m/%d/', default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: `thumb/20/08/18/image.jpeg` is the path *to the image uploaded*, which should be stored *"as-is"*. If not, you can't reference the image later.

Comment: but it's storing with each image, i am storing multiple images in relation...could it be possible that i can define this `thumb` path at once...

Comment: *"manipulating the image path"* might cause issues in your project since Django uses the path internally. So, IMHO, don't do it.

Comment: ok, understood...Thanks for clearing my confusion

Comment: could you please check this question also...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467647/how-to-display-product-in-popup-in-django