# How to display Foreign key Data in Django view page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i have relation between `Project` and `ProjectFloorPlan`, and i want to display `ProjectFloorPlan` data in my template. Please let me know how i can display the `ForeignKey` data in my template.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    slug=models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name


class ProjectFloorPlan(models.Model):
    project=models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name='projectfloorplan', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    floorplan_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='floorplan_image')
    bhk=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bed=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project.name
```

here is my `project.html` file where i am trying o display `ProjectFloorPlan` data...but it's displaying nothing

```
{% fot i in project.projectfloorplan_set.all %}
<tr>
    <td>{{i.bhk}}</td>
    <td>{{i.bed}}</td>
    
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: could you please provide me the solution of this question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465861/how-to-stop-folder-name-to-store-in-databse-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set `related_name='projectfloorplan'`, you don't have to use **`_set`** notation to access the reverse FK.

So, use **`project.projectfloorplan.all`** instead of `project.projectfloorplan_set.all`

```
{% for i in project.projectfloorplan.all %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ i.bhk }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.bed }}</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
```